# Chef Attributes: does file name matter?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

When I create attributes in my cookbook's attributes /attributes/default.rb things work fine.

If I add a recipe to my cookbook, say /recipes/dofubar.rb, I expect that attributes defined in /attributes/dofubar.rb to be loaded.  They do not appear to be.

Is there a way to define one set of default attributes for one recipe and other sets for other recipes?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no correlation between attribute file names and recipes. All files in the `attributes/` folder are loaded in order during the start of the Chef Client run. Even if you name an attribute.rb file the same as a recipe, Chef makes no correlation. All attribute files will be loaded each time.

Comment: Why so? It seems logical to correlate attribute and recipe file name. And if one wants to load some other attribute file, then `include_attribute` is the way.

Comment: As a little note here: when loading the attribute files, the `default.rb` will always be loaded first. After that, all the other attribute files in the cookbook will be loaded in alphabetical order.

Comment: @sethvargo You are one of the authors of Chef. At least you work there :) Whom else should we ask?

Comment: What is the point of allowing multiple attribute files in a cookbook, if they are all loaded automatically?

Comment: @JanHettich For organisational purposes... say I have a bunch of attributes specific to a single template. If I ever need to add, edit or delete them it becomes a lot easier if they grouped.